# Remember me in Spring security to remember only user-name

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring security in my application and wish to know if there is a way to "ask" spring to only remember the user-name of the user that comes to the application (by means of the remember-me checkbox).
What I could gather from the reference documentation is that Spring is able to save the userName and the password of the user, and directly log him/her in the next time. But what I want is that user be taken to the login page each time he comes back, but with his user-name already typed in.

Ofcourse if Spring doesn't have a way to do this, I would need to implement some cookie storage logic to take care of this requirement.

Many thanks for your answers as always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you need to set a cookie containing the user name after authentication, and access it during rendering of the login page.

If you use Spring Security 3.x, the former can be done by subclassing `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` (`SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is the default implementation) and setting a cookie with `response.addCookie()`.

The latter is a regular cookie access (`request.getCookies()`, etc).

Comment: Thanks mate. So is it confirmed, that Spring Security f/w itself doesn't provide a way to remember only the user-name (it can remember only user-sessions) on the application?

Comment: @PaiS: Yes, Spring Security's Remember Me doesn't support this scenario, and there are no other features for it.